# To obtain the probability density function of a complicated function of six independent random varibles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here is the super complicated function:
$$Z = \frac{{\left( {CE + DF + 1} \right)\left( {CA + DB + 1} \right)}}{{ABCD + \left( {CA + DB + 1} \right)}}$$
where $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are independent random variables all with positive values, and the probability density function for them are ${f_A},{f_B},{f_C},{f_D},{f_E},{f_F}$ respectively.
Here are my steps:
$$\eqalign{
  & Z = \frac{{\left( {CE + DF + 1} \right)\left( {CA + DB + 1} \right)}}{{ABCD + \left( {CA + DB + 1} \right)}}  \cr 
  & {\text{  }} = \frac{{\left( {CE + DF + 1} \right)\left( {CA + DB + 1} \right)}}{{\left( {CA + 1} \right)\left( {BD + 1} \right)}} \cr} $$ 
Let ${Z_1} = \left( {CE + DF + 1} \right),{Z_2} = \left( {CA + DB + 1} \right),{Z_3} = \left( {CA + 1} \right)\left( {BD + 1} \right)$, I can use basis random theory to obtain the pdf of ${Z_1}$,${Z_2}$ and  ${Z_3}$, because all of the components are independent, but after that, ${Z_1}$,${Z_2}$ and  ${Z_3}$ are correlated, they have common components, for example, when I want to obtain the pdf of ${Z_1}{Z_2}$,their joint pdf cannot be written as$$pd{f_{{Z_1}{Z_2}}} = pd{f_{{Z_1}}} \cdot pd{f_{{Z_2}}}$$, because they both have $C$,$D$, such that they are correlated. So, any good method to deal with this case?

Comment: Thanks for your correction

Comment: The last paragraph in the question is a convincing argument that it has no satisfying answer.

Comment: but in my opinion, we know where this correlation comes from, there must be some way to handle this, but i don't know it.